# Calculus by Spivak, Chapter 22 problem 13 (a)

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $f$ is increasing on $[1,\infty)$. Show that
$f(1)+...+f(n-1)<\int_{1}^{n}f(x)dx<f(2)+...+f(n)$ .
Rigorous proof, please!

Comment: What have you done? What do you know? This is standard if you have heard of Riemannian Rectangles.

Comment: Are you talking about the fact that it would be obvious had one taken a look at the geometrical representation? I do not know how to link (rigorously) f(i) to that integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** By the Mean Value Theorem and FTC you have

$$\int_1^ n f(x) dx - \int_1^{n-1} f(x) dx = f(c)  \, \mbox{ for some } c \in (n-1,n)$$

You can easely get a rigurous proof from here.

Comment: How could one see this geometrically?

Comment: @user68659   The difference on the LHS is $\int_{n-1}^n f(x)dx$. Since the function is increasing, this difference is less than the rectangle with the height $f(n)$ and more than the rectangle with the height $f(n-1)$

Answer (score 2):

We know that for any function $f$ such that $m<f<M$ on $[a,b]$ then $\displaystyle m(b-a) \le \int_{a}^b f(x) dx\le M(b-a)$ . In your case let $a=j$ and $b=j+1$ when $x\in [j,j+1]$ we have $f(j) \le f(x) \le f(j+1)$ since $f$ is increasing so by the above $$f(j) \le \displaystyle \int_{j}^{j+1}f(x)dx \le f(j+1)$$

Apply this inequality from $1$ to $n$ and add.

Answer (score 0):

The MVT can not be used in proving since you do not know if $f(x)$ is continuous. Since $f(x)$ is increasing in $[k-1,k]$ for $k\ge 2$, we have 
$$ f(k-1)\le f(x)\le f(k), \forall x\in[k-1,k]. $$
So
$$ f(k-1)\le \int_{k-1}^kf(x)dx\le f(k). $$
Thus
$$ \sum_{k=2}^nf(k-1)\le \sum_{k=2}^n\int_{k-1}^kf(x)dx\le \sum_{k=2}^nf(k) $$
which is what you want.

Comment: Isn't this identical to the answer I posted?